# How to factor $2x^4-11x^3-44x^2+149x+84$

Tags: factoring

I am doing something for math, and I need to factor $$2x^4-11x^3-44x^2+149x+84.$$
How do we factor it?

Comment: Have you tried writing it as two quadratics?  $$(x^2+ax+b)(2x^2+Cx+d)$$

Comment: @abiessu Honestly, I dont know how to do any of the stuff. I missed the lesson in school.

Comment: In that case, you can just use trial and error-Try substituting some values between $\pm1$ and $\pm10$. See if makes the equation equal to zero and then do long division.

Comment: try the integer divisors of $$84$$ this is the first step

Comment: @John Trial and error can be made more efficient with the rational root theorem.  You only need to try roots of the form $\frac{a}{b}$ where $a$ divides 84 and $b$ divides 2.  (Don't forget negatives!)

Comment: @btilly, you're absolutely right.

Comment: The general method to factor a quartic polynomial $f(x)$ is to use Ferrari's method to get the solutions $a,b,c,d$ to the equation $f(x)=0$ and then the factorization would be $f(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took (another) John's suggestion in the comments and ran through integers between $-10$ and $+10$, to come up with three of the four roots:  $-4, 3, 7$.

So the polynomial factors to:

$$(x+4)(x-3)(x-7)(Ax+B)$$

Since we have $2x^4$ in the polynomial, we have $A=2$.

The $x^0$ term is $84$, and the constant terms multiply together to $84$, so $B=1$.

This makes the fourth root $-1/2$ and we have finally

$$2x^4-11x^3-44x^2+149x+84 = (x+4)(x-3)(x-7)(2x+1).$$